# How to add circle on click event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you tell me how to add circle on click event in JavaScript? Actually, I want to achieve that if user click anywhere in `div` element, it add circle at that position. Currently, it added anywhere *not added in correct position*. It should be added where user clicks.

[This](https://plnkr.co/edit/P8fD45krVoQRhVCsJoAy?p=preview) is my code.

```
$(function(){
  $('#fx').click(function(e){
    var circle=$('<div class="circle"></div>');
    circle.css('top',e.pageX);
    circle.css('left',e.pageX);
    $('#fx').append(circle);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the circle to start exactly at the point where you clicked, the top is supposed to be `e.pageY`.

Then you will have to negate (r) to point it to the origin. As the radius for the circle is `15px`, it translates to

```
circle.css('top',e.pageY - 15);
circle.css('left',e.pageX - 15)
```

**[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lhwfOGPG71R1tFwPqkyI?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks but I refector my code culd you pls tell me why it is not wrking https://plnkr.co/edit/P8fD45krVoQRhVCsJoAy?p=preview

Comment: actually I  changed `jQuery` to `#` sign

Comment: May be you did not fork a new one. It is still pointing to the old changes. Check this link https://plnkr.co/edit/lhwfOGPG71R1tFwPqkyI?p=preview

Comment: That is because `#` is not a valid identifier. For more info you can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names

Comment: A correction is needed to place the circle center exactly at the mouse arrow tip.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the following line of code:

```
circle.css('top', e.pageY);
```

Comment: y it is not working https://plnkr.co/edit/P8fD45krVoQRhVCsJoAy?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

If you want the circle to be positionned **EXACTLY** were the user clicks...

You have to know that `pageX` and `pageY` doesn't give you the position of the "tip" of the mouse arrow... But the center of the mouse icon displayed.

So, ""usual icons" dimentions are 20px x 20px.

I have updated your Plunker.
I have added a "dot" to show the exact position where a user expects it to be the center, which is the tip of the arrow.

I made the circle much bigger to be sure about the middle.

See by yourself on this [**forked and updated Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ONA4cuTuNiCMHQqkQFah?p=preview).

Code is:

```
$(function(){
  $('#fx').click(function(e){

    var width = 300;        // Width of the element has to be hard coded here;
    var radius = width/2;
    console.log(radius);    // Since element is a circle, the radius is enought to set position.

    var mouseTip = 10;      // But mouse arrow tip has to be taken in account.

    var circle=$('<div class="circle"></div>');
      circle.css('top',e.pageY-radius-mouseTip);
      circle.css('left',e.pageX-radius-mouseTip);
      $('#fx').append(circle);

    var dot=$('<div class="dot"></div>');       // This is only intended to show where user REALLY wants to clic
                                                // and the FACT that there is a correction to apply.
      dot.css('top',e.pageY-mouseTip);
      dot.css('left',e.pageX-mouseTip);
      $('#fx').append(dot);
  });
});
```

So this is great for the "arrow" default cursor, it will need another mouse correction value if you use the "pointer" icon.